# Replace USB port on logic board Mac mini late 2012

Tags: usb, mac-mini

The USB ports stopped working. I tried resetting NVRAM, and all non- physical solutions. It seems it is a hardware malfunction, so is it possible to replace the USB port only on the logic board of a  Mac mini Late 2012 - 2.3 ghz Core i7?

Answer (score 2):

It's *possible* but difficult, especially if you aren't experienced with soldering electrical devices.

The other problem is that your USB ports may be fine. For example, the problem could be with the USB controller on the logic board (especially if all of your USB ports stopped working!)

While your question states you have tried all non physical solutions, that doesn't actually specify *what* you've tried. So I'd recommend you reset the System Management Controller (SMC) and test your hardware.

**Reset the SMC**

1. Shut down your Mac mini
2. Unplug it from power
3. Wait 15 seconds
4. Plug the power cord back in
5. Wait for an additional 5 seconds
6. Press the power button to turn it back on

**Run Apple Hardware Test**

Your model Mac mini uses Apple Hardware Test. To use this, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your Mac mini
2. Restart your Mac mini
3. Press and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key before the gray startup screen appears.
4. After a while, Apple Hardware Test (AHT) will start.
5. When prompted, select your language and click the right arrow.
6. When the AHT console appears, you can choose to run Basic tests by clicking the Test button. However, I suggest you select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox before you click the Test button.
7. Your test results will appear in the window in the bottom-right of the console.

**Note 1:** that the extended test will take some time. Take a note of the results and report back.

**Note 2:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer
I tried  resetting the SMC before and it did not work,
Unfortunately my keyboard is usb not wireless, I’ll borrow one from a friend on Sunday to run the AHT,  
Also I forgot to mention the reason why the usb stoped (probably), I moved to a new apartment and I plugged all the usb devices: scanner printers hard disks (around 10-11 devices) and they were all turned on before I started the computer, once the computer booted I had a (USB device drawing too much power) error message , and all the usb went down , I researched and did all the  suggested solutions.

Comment: Although you are right I might not be experienced with soldering electrical devices, but I can remove the logic board and take it to a local electronic soldering specialist ,
thank you again for your response and I will report you back with the  AHT result once I finish it (next Sunday I guess )

Comment: Unfortunately, if all four USB ports are gone then it is quite possible you've caused damaged further up the line and this typically would mean replacing the logic board. However, one thing to consider is the option of using an adapter cable. What I mean is that you also have an Ethernet port, FireWire port and Thunderbolt port. So using one of these with an adapter may be a better option for you (i.e. FireWire to USB adapter, ethernet to USB adapter, Thunderbolt to USB adapter). Either way, all the best with it.

Comment: Thank you for your concern ,
I ran the Apple Hardware (Extending) Test and it gave me an alert:
Apple Hardware Test has detected an error 
4HDD/30/40000005: SATA(0.0)
Pass Number : 1,
Total Time Testing : 33mins 10 secs
hope this helps , Thanks

Comment: As for using adapter cables from FireWire and Ethernet, for my knowledge I think it is not possible , the possible is vice versa it is built to convert the usb to FireWire or Ethernet and dosen’t work on reverse (which I need),
But as for the Thunderbolt you are completely right   and I’m saving this as a last option  , as the  Thunderbolt docks are a bit expensive to m

Comment: That error indicates a hard drive problem. Part of your drive has already failed and the rest will likely fail soon. **If you haven't already got a full backup, organise one now!** Unfortunately, once AHT finds a problem it'll stop running more tests, so we may not know for sure what's happening with the rest of your logic board etc. It's also possible that HD error is a false positive because of a *different* logic board problem, but with no functioning USB ports it'll be difficult for you to test for this possibility. Either way, you have an additional problem to just your USB ports.

Comment: Yes, I got it, although there is no symptoms yet of any failure of the hdd but I have to replace it and emigrate to the new one, then run the test again. will do this soon, thank you for your patience, will report you when done.

Comment: hi  Monomeeth,
Thank you for your patience with me ,
it was not  a false positive , the hard drive was failed indeed , anyhow finally I managed to rescue all my data and replaced it wit a new one, then I ran the Apple Hardware (Extending) Test and the result was surprisingly “No trouble found” pass number 1 .. I re-ran the test again pass number 2 got the same result “No trouble found”  yet still the usb problem exist.

Comment: hello,any suggestions ?